# How to move all coordinates in geojson feature collection in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, coordinates, geojson

I receive geojson data (FeatureCollection) that storing some objects with geometry.

What's the best way for move/shift/transform all points in all geometries in all features in FeatureCollection?

I am writing on Kotlin and using jacksonObjectMapper for parse this data and now the only way that I see is change every coordinate in cycle for each type of geometry

For example:

FeatureCollection

```
{
    "type":"FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type":"Feature",
            "properties": {
                "background": "WALLS_LOAD_BEARING"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type":"MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates":[
                    [[[10.0, 20.0], [15.0, 20.0], ... ,[10.0, 25.0]]],
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type":"Feature",
            "properties": {
                "background":"PARTITIONS"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type":"MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates": [...]
            }
        },
        {
            "type":"Feature",
            "properties": {
                "background":"WALLS_LOAD_BEARING"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type":"LineString",
                "coordinates": [[10.0, 20.0], ... ]
            }
        },
    ],
}
```

Coordinates:

```
moveX = 10.0
moveY = 5.0
```

I expect to receive

```
{
    "type":"FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type":"Feature",
            "properties": {
                "background": "WALLS_LOAD_BEARING"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type":"MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates":[
                    [[[20.0, 25.0], [25.0, 25.0], ... ,[20.0, 30.0]]],
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type":"Feature",
            "properties": {
                "background":"PARTITIONS"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type":"MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates": [...]
            }
        },
        {
            "type":"Feature",
            "properties": {
                "background":"WALLS_LOAD_BEARING"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type":"LineString",
                "coordinates": [[20.0, 25.0], ... ]
            }
        },
    ],
}
```

Comment: "and now the only way that I see is change every coordinate in cycle for each type of geometry" And what's wrong with that?

Comment: Does not want to re-invent the wheel if it already exists

Comment: Well there probably is some GeoJSON library that does this for you. Try doing some googling. Note that Stack Overflow is not an appropriate place to ask for recommendations of external libraries.

Comment: Of course i googling before ask and did not find any that could help me. I've just hoped that I'm not the first who need to do this

Answer (score 0):

My version

```
object GeometryUtils {

    private val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper()

    private fun movePointToCoordinate(point: Point, coordinateX: Double, coordinateY: Double) {
        point.coordinates.longitude += coordinateX
        point.coordinates.latitude += coordinateY
    }

    private fun moveMultiPointToCoordinate(multiPoint: MultiPoint, coordinateX: Double, coordinateY: Double) {
        multiPoint.coordinates.forEach { coordinate ->
            coordinate.longitude += coordinateX
            coordinate.latitude += coordinateY
        }
    }

    private fun moveLineStringToCoordinate(lineString: LineString, coordinateX: Double, coordinateY: Double) {
        lineString.coordinates.forEach { coordinate ->
            coordinate.longitude += coordinateX
            coordinate.latitude += coordinateY
        }
    }

    private fun moveMultiLineStringToCoordinate(multiLineString: MultiLineString, coordinateX: Double, coordinateY: Double) {
        multiLineString.coordinates.forEach { lineString ->
            lineString.forEach { coordinate ->
                coordinate.longitude += coordinateX
                coordinate.latitude += coordinateY
            }
        }
    }

    private fun movePolygonToCoordinate(polygon: Polygon, coordinateX: Double, coordinateY: Double) {
        polygon.coordinates.forEach { lineString ->
            lineString.forEach { coordinate ->
                coordinate.longitude += coordinateX
                coordinate.latitude += coordinateY
            }
        }
    }

    private fun moveMultiPolygonToCoordinate(multiPolygon: MultiPolygon, coordinateX: Double, coordinateY: Double) {
        multiPolygon.coordinates.forEach { polygon ->
            polygon.forEach { lineString ->
                lineString.forEach { coordinate ->
                    coordinate.longitude += coordinateX
                    coordinate.latitude += coordinateY
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun moveGeoJsonObjectToCoordinate(geometry: GeoJsonObject, coordinateX: Double, coordinateY: Double): GeoJsonObject {
        when (geometry::class) {
            Point::class -> movePointToCoordinate(geometry as Point, coordinateX, coordinateY)
            MultiPoint::class -> moveMultiPointToCoordinate(geometry as MultiPoint, coordinateX, coordinateY)
            LineString::class -> moveLineStringToCoordinate(geometry as LineString, coordinateX, coordinateY)
            MultiLineString::class -> moveMultiLineStringToCoordinate(geometry as MultiLineString, coordinateX, coordinateY)
            Polygon::class -> movePolygonToCoordinate(geometry as Polygon, coordinateX, coordinateY)
            MultiPolygon::class -> moveMultiPolygonToCoordinate(geometry as MultiPolygon, coordinateX, coordinateY)
        }
        return geometry
    }

    fun moveGeometryToCoordinate(json: String, coordinateX: Double, coordinateY: Double): String =
        mapper.writeValueAsString(
            moveGeoJsonObjectToCoordinate(
                mapper.readValue(json, GeoJsonObject::class.java),
                coordinateX,
                coordinateY,
            ),
        )

    fun moveFeatureCollectionToCoordinate(json: String, coordinateX: Double, coordinateY: Double): String {
        val featureCollection = mapper.readValue(json, FeatureCollection::class.java)
        featureCollection.features.forEach { feature ->
            feature.geometry = moveGeoJsonObjectToCoordinate(feature.geometry, coordinateX, coordinateY)
        }
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(featureCollection)
    }
}
```